# Error getting outlook.com tasks using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

url:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/XXXXXX/outlook/taskGroups

error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "RequestBroker-ParseUri",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'Outlook'.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "7f5e2c9b-0999-48d3-9cfe-a4b888b0b33c",
      "date": "2017-11-24T22:17:08"
    }
  }
}